# issue changing the color of a picture in Java

Tags: java, image, colors

I got given some code for calculating R, G and B values from an rgb value. They look like this:

```
public static int getR(int rgb) {
        return (rgb >> 16) & 0xff; 
    }

public static int getG(int rgb) {
    return (rgb >> 8) & 0xff;
}

public static int getB(int rgb) {
    return rgb & 0xff;
}
```

now I have to do the following excercise. I am changing the correct part of the image, but everything is colored black.

```
/**
     * Converts a picture by dividing it in three equal parts along the X axis. 
     * In the first (left) part, only the red component is drawn. In the second 
     * (middle) part, only the green component is drawn. In the third (right) part,
     * only the blue component is drawn.
     * 
     * @param pixels The input pixels.
     * @return The output pixels.
     */
    public static int[][] andyWarhol(int[][] pixels) {
        int i, j;

        //Convert red part:
        for (i = 0; i < pixels.length / 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < pixels[0].length; j++) {
                pixels[i][j] = Colors.getR(pixels[i][j]);
            }
        }

        //Convert yellow part:
        for (i = pixels.length / 3; i < pixels.length * 2 / 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < pixels[0].length; j++) {
                pixels[i][j] = Colors.getG(pixels[i][j]);
            }
        }

        //Convert blue part:
        for (i = pixels.length * 2 / 3; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < pixels[0].length; j++) {
                pixels[i][j] = Colors.getB(pixels[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return pixels;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide getG() and getB() as well?

Comment: I added it to the original text, no idea how to do it in the comments. I feel like the returns of the getR() etc. functions are not the type of number you need to write into the image array

Comment: that is where you should have added it anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Okay yea as I suspected I had to turn every value for R, B and G into an rbg value again. Makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your alpha is 0 (transparent).
I don't know how it's used, but colors in java are often 'argb'.
Try with (color | 0xff_00_00_00)